# Twilio Programmable Video chatroom

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, twilio, twilio-video

i am willing to create video rooms with only 2 persons in it with twillio & node.js (express) & socket.io and for seeing how it works i cloned github quickstart from this [link](https://github.com/lwilio/group-rooms-demo):

it had a few errors:

it could not recognize "Twilio" in javascipt so i changed existing link with cdn link

also i changed socket.io-client with with   `<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

and deleted DetectRTC from code because it was causing errors in console and cleared all errors in console
but it still does not works, regardless it does not logs any error.
what is problem with this code?
if anyone can fix it please post your answer below. Thanks!

(by the way this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im0_nwZlefY) guided me to that quickstart and as i see code in this video works but this quickstart does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That quickstart you are using there is not our official one. I recommend you take a look at [the official Twilio Video quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) and follow the instructions there to see how it all works. The team that looks after our quickstarts keeps this one up to date with the latest changes in the library and should work better for you.

Comment: yes i took a look at that quickstart too but i liked quickstart i chose because it was autoconnecting to room where other participant was waiting and in official quickstart you have to write room name

Comment: Well sure, but this one also isn’t working. What I’d recommend is getting the official QuickStart working, seeing how it works, then building your own version that does exactly what you want it to do based on what you learned.

Comment: thank you for advise, i did it, but can you give me an small example of one-one video chatroom example (skull), i will be really glad, and that would be a great start for me

Comment: That’s not how Stack Overflow works really. What would be best is if you try to build it yourself and then if you have a specific problem that you can’t solve, ask a question on SO. You already have multi party chat, you just need to restrict it to one-one. Good luck, and I’ll be here on SO if you have trouble once you’ve tried it yourself.

Comment: by the way i also tried your project and it did not work too and can you take a look at it too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992314/one-to-one-video-chatroom-with-twilio-video-webrtc-socket-io